# Visualizing Newton-Raphson method for finding zeroes of a function

Tags: performance, beginner, matlab, numerical-methods, octave

I have created a program to visualize the working of Newton-Raphson method to find the zeroes of a function:

**newton.m:**

```
% Dummy statement to avoid writing function in the first line and making it a 'function file' instead of a 'script file'
1;


% The function to find zeroes of.
% The function is specifically chosen to not have any zeroes
% so as to show the weakness of Newton's method.
function y = f(x)
    y = (x - 5).^2 + 5;
endfunction


% The derivative of f(x)
function y = fd(x)
    y = 2 * (x - 5);
endfunction


% Initial guess
x0 = 1.5;

% Max number of iterations
itermax = 20;

% Epsilon value initialized to a very large value
eps = 1;

% A vector for storing the history of the approximate roots
xvals = x0;

% Number of iterations done
itercount = 0;

% Required for plotting f(x) vs x
x = linspace(0, 10, 100);

% Create a figure whose output is not rendered on the screen
% Not working currently; supposedly a bug in Octave
% A workaround is to use gnuplot instead of qt - `graphics_toolkit gnuplot`
% but this is very slow.
% Uncomment the following to activate the feature once the bug is fixed
% figure('Visible','off');

% The main loop
while eps >= 1e-5 && itercount <= itermax
    % x1 = New value of root
    % x0 = Current value of root
    x1 = x0 - f(x0) / fd(x0);

    % Plot f(x)
    % Plot a line passing through points [x0, f(x0)] and [x1, 0]
    % Plot a line passing through points [x1, 0] and [x1, f(x1)]
    % Plot a line passing through points [x0, 0] and [x0, f(x0)]
    plot(x, f(x), ";f(x);", [x0 x1], [f(x0) 0], "-r;f'(x);", [x1 x1], [0 f(x1)], ":r", [x0 x0], [0 f(x0)], ":r");
    title('f(x) = (x-5)^2 + 5');


    % Set limits for the axes shown in the plots
    xlim([0 10]);
    ylim([0 30]);

    % Label the two consecutive zeroes on the X-axis
    text(x0, -2, sprintf('x%d', itercount), 'color', 'red');
    text(x1, -2, sprintf('x%d', itercount+1), 'color', 'red');

    % Print the plot to a file
    filename = sprintf('output/%05d.jpg', itercount);
    print(filename)

    % Append the zero to the array of zeroes calculated so far
    xvals = [xvals; x1];

    % Calculate the epsilon value
    eps = abs(x1-x0);

    x0 = x1;
    itercount = itercount+1;
end


% Print the result of the iteration
xvals
f_zero = f(xvals(end))
eps
itercount
```

This program produces a series of images which I have combined to create an animation:

[image: Simulation of Newton's Raphson method on a function not having any zeroes]

The command I used to convert the images is:

```
convert -delay 100 -loop 0 *.png animation.gif
```

This code is also stored [here](https://github.com/Anmol-Singh-Jaggi/Machine-Learning/tree/master/newton_raphson).

I would like to get it reviewed on the following:

- Octave conventions and coding patterns (This is my first programming attempt using Octave)
- Any improvement on the algorithm itself
- Readability and performance of the code
- Method and quality of producing animations

Answer (score 5):

**Conventions, coding patterns and readability**

Overall, your code looks nice! I have never seen a code where you insert a line in the beginning to avoid the script being interpreted as a function. It works, but I wouldn't do it like that.

The two functions you have are very simple. There is *1: no recursion. 2: no loops 3: no handling of invalid input*. For such functions you can simply create [anonymous functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/v4.0.0/Anonymous-Functions.html). This way you can avoid the first line of code in your script.

```
% The function to find zeroes of.
% The function is specifically chosen to not have any zeroes
% so as to show the weakness of Newton's method.
f = @(x) (x - 5).^2 + 5; 

% The derivative of f(x)
fd = @(x) 2 * (x - 5);
```

You have very descriptive variable names. However, `eps` is not one of them, as `eps` is a [built-in function and variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/v4.0.1/Mathematical-Constants.html).

You have a growing vector in your loop `xvals = [xvals; x1];`. This is not recommended, as [it is very slow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16188190/2338750). It's faster to pre-allocate memory for a vector that will be "large enough", and trim it down afterwards:

```
xvals = zeros(20,1);
while ...
...
end
xvals = xvals(1:iter);  % or xvals(iter+1:end) = [];
```

Also, if you don't want to pre-allocate memory, you can increase performance by substituting `xvals = [xvals; x1]` with:

```
xvals(end+1) = x1;
```

You should use `< itermax` instead of `<= itermax` in the loop condition. Otherwise you'll end up with `itercount = itermax + 1`.

---

**Note: Always try to keep compatibility with MATLAB when programming in Octave.**

- Don't use `itercount ++` instead of `itercount = itercount + 1`, because it's easier.
- Don't do `a = b = c = 0` because it's easier.
- Don't do inline assignments `b = (a=3) * a` just because you can.
- And it might not be recommended by everyone, but *I* recommend you to use `end` instead of `endfunction`, `endif` etc to keep compatibility with MATLAB.

This is all I can do for now... Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

Although I'm with Stewie Griffin in many points I want to highlight where I disagree.

Octave tries to complete the Matlab language and therefore constructs like
`itercount++`, `a = b = c = 0` (which should be familiar to every C rogrammer) were added. If you don't have to be Matlab compatible just use them. They make your code easier to read and more fun to write. In my opinion the `endfor`, `endwhile`, `endfunction` keywords also increase the readability.

Btw, both graphics toolkits qt and fltk can use OSMesa for offscreen rendering if you use a Mesa based GPU driver on GNU/Linux. (your "bug" comment)

Octave conventions and coding patterns:

- Using `1;` at the beginning of your script is a common technique, keep it this way.
- I suggest using the Octave style guide: http://wiki.octave.org/Octave_style_guide
- break the long plot command into

`plot ( x, f(x), ";f(x);",
       [x0 x1], [f(x0) 0], "-r;f'(x);",
       [x1 x1], [0 f(x1)], ":r",
       [x0 x0], [0 f(x0)], ":r");`

- Create the output directory before blindly trying to write to it: `mkdir ("output");`
- I would keep the last 3..5 steps in the plots and/or let the last steps vanish (decrease saturation)